# Pass and return an array from WebAssembly

Tags: javascript, arrays, c, webassembly

I want to take an array in JavaScript, pass it to WebAssembly, have WASM transform the array, and have WASM return the transformed array back to JavaScript.

e.g.

```js
/* main.js */

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// WASM code that squares the above array
const squaredArray = wasmModule.exports.squareArray(array);

console.log(squaredArray); // [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

I figured I could achieve this in C by iterating over the array, like

```c
/* square.c */

// the array variable is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
    array[i] = array[i] * array[i];
}
return array;
```

and compiling to WASM by doing

```
emcc square.c -o square.wasm -s WASM=1
```

However, some research has lead me to believe that it's much more complicated than this, involving allocating and de-allocating memory, and a bit more to do on the C end.

Could anybody give me a boilerplate example of passing and returning an array from WebAssembly? I would appreciate any help you could give. I'm new to WebAssembly and haven't used any other programming language than JS.

If another language that can compile to WASM would better suited for this (C++, Go, Rust), I would be happy for examples on those too.

Comment: You can copy the array into the WASM's memory, call the WASM function and then copy the results back. What address in the WASM's memory? well that's up to you... if your WASM program has `malloc` you could call `malloc` to get an address.

Comment: See... I don't really understand all of that, or how I could implement it. No doubt you're right, I was just wondering if someone could give a very simple boilerplate example.

Comment: You could make a global variable to hold the numbers.

Comment: Where should the global variable be? C or JS? I need to do the calculations in WASM.

Comment: [This resource](https://rob-blackbourn.github.io/blog/webassembly/wasm/array/arrays/javascript/c/2020/06/07/wasm-arrays.html) may help you.

Comment: C can only access variables in C, including parameters, which have to be fixed sizes and therefore cannot hold arrays with different sizes. It can't access anything in JS except by calling import functions.

Answer (score 0):

Rust makes it easy with `wasm-bindgen` and `wasm-pack`.  I used Node.js for quick testing.

Quick setup:

```
cargo new --lib --vcs=none wasm_pass_return_ary

cd wasm_pass_return_ary

cargo add js-sys

cargo add wasm-bindgen
```

Inside `Cargo.toml`, add this before `[dependencies]`:

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

I'm assuming that the parameter is guaranteed to be a signed 32-bit integer.

**src\lib.rs**

```
use js_sys::Int32Array;
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn square_array(ary: &[i32]) -> Int32Array {
    let out = ary.into_iter()
        .map(|x| x.pow(2))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
        
    Int32Array::from(&out[..])
}
```

Build with `wasm-pack build --target nodejs`

**main.js** file at the project root:

```
const wasmModule = require("./pkg/wasm_pass_return_ary.js");
const { square_array } = wasmModule;

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const squaredArray = square_array(array);

console.log(squaredArray);  // the data type is Int32Array

console.log([...squaredArray]);
```

Run with `node .\main.js`